# Remove brain region variation from DESeq2 design

Tags: r, pca, data-processing, rna-seq

Fairly new to this so I would appreciate your patience!

So I have RNA-seq gene expression counts data downloaded from GTEx using the recount3 package in r:

```
gtex_rse <- recount3::create_rse_manual(
    project = "BRAIN",
    project_home = "data_sources/gtex",
    organism = "human",
    annotation = "gencode_v26",
    type = "gene"
)
```

And there is definitely some variation attributable to brain region (this is including just sex in the design):
[image: PCA plot of gtex data colored by collection region]

I want to compare this expression data to TCGA patient tumor tissue data, but the TCGA data does not specify the brain region of collection. Thus, I'd like to compare by tumor vs control expression differences without influence of brain region. Are there any suggestions for minimizing influence of brain region on tumor vs control differential expression analysis? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the visualization of group by color coding should not affect the clustering per se. However, there could be differences in gene expression profiles across brain regions that are inherent their to cell populations. This is why comparing across databases can be tricky since the samples could have been prepared in different ways experimentally. Although, you can try deleting the brain label column and see whether there is a difference.